# Simple SQL update query is slow on small table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sqlite

I've recently migrated to database storage for my PHP sessions.  After making the session handler functions I've realized that my writes are.. slow.

The following query takes 0.04 seconds on MySQL and 0.08 seconds on SQLite.  This doesn't seem slow, until I realize that the table only has 6 rows on a new set up.

```
UPDATE sm_sessions
    SET last_access =  '1463104877'
    WHERE session_id = 'smsess-5734112c09619927459593e9866792515f74ba3115d3a1093b3a31018'
    LIMIT 1
```

And, here's the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sm_sessions` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session_id` char(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `session_data` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `last_access` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `session_id` (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=57 ;
```

Note that I've tried everything, including the following:

- added the primary key and auto increment "id" (this field didn't exist in the beginning, tried adding it to see if it would effect performance)
- tried primary key, unique index, and regular index on session_id
- tried removing all indexes
- tried modifying the query to update using the id in the where clause instead of the 64 character session_id (no improvement)
- tried using REPLACE INTO and ON DUPLICATE KEY update (worse)
- Ran the query directly from mysql cli and phpmyadmin (and sqlite cli and sqliteadmin) - same performance, so I know it's not php or pdo slowing it down

I understand that 0.04 seconds isn't that bad.  But, the reads complete in 0.0006 seconds or so.  If I have 10 writes that's 0.4 seconds.  And, yes, I know that reads are usually always faster than writes, but 0.04 or worse sounds extremely bad for a table with 6 rows, a new set up, and such a simple query.

I feel like this update query should take 0.01s at WORST and usually in the range of 0.005s.  Is this a reasonable expectation?

This is done locally but it seems that even on a different server the writes would be relatively slow because everything else is fast.  I can post code or mysql/sqlite settings but I feel like that shouldn't matter on a recently made table with 6 rows.

What's wrong?

EDIT|  Updating the mysql table that is created when installing mysql, a simple update query takes 0.005 seconds.  Same database server.  Something's wrong.

EDIT2| Changing the storage engine from InnoDB to MyISAM made the query run much faster - 0.0009 seconds.  I would mark this as solved, and I probably will, but does anyone know why this sped it up?

EDIT3| Sorry for all of the edits, but anyone reading should know that I found the solution in the answer below.

Comment: Is that 0.04 seconds or 0.04ms? Either way, unless you're experiencing serious problems with performance, this doesn't sound like the end of the world.

Comment: It's 0.04 seconds (40 milliseconds).  I feel like it is the end of the world because while using database session management every session write is going to take 0.04 seconds.  Plus, I'm writing an open source software and without this the page loads in under 0.01 seconds.  Also, whether it's the end of the world or not, I feel like it still shouldn't be happening.  I added an edit above.

Comment: If you're that freaked out about these sorts of database calls you're in trouble already. You could use something like [Redis](http://redis.io) if you have a small amount of data to store, it's usually faster than MySQL, but it's more limiting.

Comment: Changing the storage engine to MyISAM ran the query in 0.0009 seconds.  Why is that?

Comment: MyISAM isn't transactional, it's very brittle. Under light load it will perform better, but heavy loads suffers badly from table-level write locks. You really need to benchmark both under strain or your numbers are meaningless.

Comment: Apparently I'm not justified in wondering why a simple update takes 0.04 seconds.  That's 1 write, per user, that happens automatically everytime a session is read or written.  Without ANYTHING else, that's about 20 users simultaneously before the system goes over load.  If anyone has an answer besides "don't worry about it", or "you're freaked out", I'd be happy to listen to it.

Comment: Like I said, try it under load. If you can simulate 100 writes per second look at the 50th and 95th percentile times.

Comment: Thanks, @tadman.  Sorry for the tone.  Like any other project author, I hope for my application to have many users.  That's why I'm concerned about the slow simple write (also, performance can be a feature, rather than a detriment).  Would you be kind enough to inform me how to simulate a load?  I've never done anything like that.  I'll stop with a bunch of responses because this isn't a chat.  :)

Comment: The good news is there's a [bunch of stuff in the documentation on this very subject](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-benchmarking.html) not to mention innumerable blog posts that explain more.

Comment: Thanks to benchmarking, I was able to figure out that the problem was that the client/server charset & collation was different from the database/table/field charset & collation.  Changing the client/server charset & collation to match the database resulted in a ~40x speed increase.

Comment: Great detective work!

Answer (score 2):

I started benchmarking using mysqlslab, thanks to @tadman's suggestion, and I've figured out the problem.

My connection and server charsets and collations were set to a mixture of latin1 and utf8.

This table is comparing strings using utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_general_ci.

After changing the connection and the server to match, I get speeds of <0.001 seconds (more than 40 times faster than the previous 0.04 seconds).

Showing my tests..

**Before** I figured out the problem, I ran the following command:

```
scott@scottsdevbox:/etc/mysql$ /usr/bin/mysqlslap --user=root --password=mypasswordhere --delimiter=";" --create="CREATE TABLE a (session_id char(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, session_data text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, last_access int(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (session_id)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci; INSERT INTO  a (session_id ,session_data ,last_access)VALUES ('smsess-57356c97a576f244771728b1cf2b22c3d05ee2a891ab34c4c60cd5fe9',  'abczyx123string',  '1463120872');" --query="UPDATE a SET last_access =  '1463120866' WHERE session_id = 'smsess-57356c97a576f244771728b1cf2b22c3d05ee2a891ab34c4c60cd5fe9' LIMIT 1" --concurrency=1 --iterations=100 --engine="InnoDB"
```

And got the usual results with the 0.04 speeds:

```
Benchmark
    Running for engine InnoDB
    Average number of seconds to run all queries: 0.046 seconds
    Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.033 seconds
    Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.211 seconds
    Number of clients running queries: 1
    Average number of queries per client: 1
```

And then, after changing my server and client charset (to utf8mb4) and collation (to utf8mb4_general_ci) to match the database and fields..

Command:

```
scott@scottsdevbox:/etc/mysql$ /usr/bin/mysqlslap --user=root --password=mypasswordhere --delimiter=";" --create="CREATE TABLE a (session_id char(64) character set utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL, session_data text character set utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci, last_access int(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (session_id))  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci; INSERT INTO  a (session_id ,session_data ,last_access)VALUES ('smsess-57356c97a576f244771728b1cf2b22c3d05ee2a891ab34c4c60cd5fe9',  'abczyx123string',  '1463120872');" --query="UPDATE a SET last_access =  '1463120866' WHERE session_id = 'smsess-57356c97a576f244771728b1cf2b22c3d05ee2a891ab34c4c60cdsed5fe9' LIMIT 1" --concurrency=1 --iterations=100 --engine="InnoDB"
```

Results:

```
Benchmark
    Running for engine InnoDB
    Average number of seconds to run all queries: 0.000 seconds
    Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.000 seconds
    Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.001 seconds
    Number of clients running queries: 1
    Average number of queries per client: 1
```

In conclusion, I learned that **changing your client and server charset and collation to match the database and tables and fields charset and collation increases query speed**.

Answer (score 0):

Every change to the database involves locking and sychronization overhead, which happens only once per transaction, and is not dependent on the amount of data accessed or written.

So it is likely that the time will not get much larger when the size of the DB increases.

To make multiple writes faster, put them all into the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

`char(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is awful for ascii strings.

- `CHAR` is fixed width, there wasting space.  In particular, that takes 4*64 (=256) bytes, regardless of the contents.
- `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` adds unnecessary complexity if the text is always letters, dash, and digits.

Switch to `VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  `session_data` can stay utf8mb4 if that is suitable.

Comment: Thanks, @Rick James, I've been wondering that.. For any value that i know will be ascii, like above, setting to ascii would be preferred, correct? Since that field will always be a-z0-9, there's no need for utf8 on that field even though the entire app as a whole is internationalized, correct?

Comment: Correct and correct.  I see that `smsess-5734112c09619927459593e9866792515f74ba3115d3a1093b3a31018` is exactly 64 bytes.  It would take 1+64 bytes (1 for length) in `VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  If you know that all your strings are 64 characters, then `CHAR` would save that 1 byte.